# How to convert the observed magnitude of a Quasar to it's bolometric luminosity?

Tags: black-hole, observational-astronomy, astrophysics, supermassive-black-hole, quasars

How can I convert the observed magnitude to Bolometric Luminosity? I know the relation for the star but should it be same for a Quasar? Basically I want to convert the X-axis of this plot to luminosity (or mass).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bolometric magnitude of a quasar can be determined by the same method as a star (using total energy radiated)......but for the fact that quasars do not radiate isotropically and this distribution is dependant on wavelength
A further complication comes as many photons are absorbed and re-emitted , etc
Some standard methods of calculation can be found here......
[Quasar bolometric corrections](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/408/3/1598/1074070)